# shallow update not allowed with github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to do a repo mirroring with github actions. There's two repositories, the first is the one containing the workflow and the second one is the one I want to push to.
When pushing from the first repository, the mirror action fails because of the error below :

! [remote rejected] origin/main -> main (shallow update not allowed)
error: failed to push some refs to '...'

Here is the workflow job :

```
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout/@v3
    - uses: pixta-dev/repository-mirroring-action@v1
      with:
        target_repo_url:
          ${{ env.URL }}
        ssh_private_key:
          ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
```

After recreating the repository containing the workflow, it didn't change anything. Should I do something with the repository I want to push to ? Knowing that I already succeed to push on it but I had to add jobs to my workflow sheet so the repository is not empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Find the answer :

Added fetch-depth which fetchs n commits -> 0 = all

I changed the code above to

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```