# Github Actions - Checkout another repo and merge a remote branch - strange behavior

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a checkout/v3 action that pulls from a remote repository

```
 - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      repository: myorg/myrepo
      ref: mybranch
      token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

And then trying to merge in a remote branch

```
  - run: |
      git config --global user.email "me@myorg.com"
      git config --global user.name "me"
      git fetch
      git merge mybranch origin/${{ env.ANOTHER_BRANCH}}
```

The first issue I am having is that this fails with an unexpected error

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

These are both branches off of main, with only 1 single letter change test commit made to ANOTHER_BRANCH.

Adding the setting --allow-unrelated-histories takes me past that error, but then I get a merge conflict.

The trouble is this is the only place I get the conflict, so I can't resolve it. If I create a pull request between from ANOTHER_BRANCH -> mybranch there are no reported conflicts. If I pull these branches down locally and do the same merge, there is no conflict. Seems the conflict is related to my GH Action use case.

Any ideas?

Comment: "*These are both branches off of main*" are you sure? Check `git branch -a --contains main`

Comment: Good call, it actually wasn't a branch off main. Doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub actions use shallow clones by default, as an optimization: there's no point in fetching the whole history if you're not going to use it!

In your use case, however, you are using the history, so you can ask for it with `fetch-depth: 0`. That will fetch the full history.

Solution, found in a different question with the same fix:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71819349/3216427

Comment: Originally I thought the other answer was it because with a fresh branch off main it started working, but then I noticed it would throw unrelated history error if main was ahead of ANOTHER_BRANCH. Setting fetch-depth fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

> These are both branches off of main

Make sure with `git branch -a --contains main`.

> [They were not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74723626/github-actions-checkout-another-repo-and-merge-a-remote-branch-strange-behav?noredirect=1#comment131882469_74723626).